# how to bind ion-picker button to keyboard enter?

Tags: ionic-framework, picker

i m using ion-picker and i have added 2 buttons on that picker, one is 'ok' button and another is 'cancel',

how to bind keyboard enter to 'ok' button?

using ionic-angular to for my application. didn't find any keyboard event binding in documentation
[ion-picker](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/picker)

```
let pickerOptions = {
    buttons: [
      {
        text: 'Cancel',
        role: 'cancel'
      },
      {
        text: 'Ok',
        handler: (selectedItem: any) =>
        {
          //
        }
      }
    ]
  };
let picker = await this.pickerController.create(pickerOptions);
picker.present();
```